# Where can I find a reference sheet with ECMAScript 5 functions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Where can I find a 1-2 page reference sheet of all of ECMAScript 5's data-types and functions?

e.g. Syntax and short explanation for: Array.prototype.forEach, Date.now, and so on.

Comment: Just a clarification: a reference sheet with all functions, not just new ECMAScript 5 functions.

Comment: Voting to close as resource rec. My live assertion-based cheatsheet: http://www.cirosantilli.com/web/js.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This site](http://dochub.io/#javascript/array.prototype) handles not only javascript but also HTML, CSS, jQuery and more.

Comment: Closest answer so far. 
While it's not a PDF and isn't printable, it does cover all JS functions from all versions in one list.

Comment: The dochub site gets the actual data on HTML, CSS and JavaScript from Mozilla Developer Network (MDN).

Comment: This site is offline

Comment: What a shame. It appears that the dochub.io open source project on github has been abandoned -- last update was 4 years ago. I loved that resource. Perhaps someone has a link to a version now served up from another site?

Answer (score 5):

You can also look at the MDN (great resource for JavaScript docs)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.8.5

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/JavaScript/ECMAScript_5_support_in_Mozilla

Answer (score 2):

This is official PDF http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

check this too http://kasia.drzyzga.pl/2011/06/ecmascript-5-object-methods-cheatsheet/

and this video is good to

ECMAScript 5: The New Parts
http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX11/EXT13